# Error in importing existing managed solution after Upgrading CRM 2013 to CRM 2015

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

We are facing an issue in CRM 2015 online which was recently upgraded from CRM 2013 online version., since Earlier back with CRM 2013, it was a smooth process.

Issue is occurring while importing same managed solution (from dev) over same managed solution (in Test environment). The exception is getting raised:

```
"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ_LocalizedLabelCheck'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'MetadataSchema.LocalizedLabel'. The duplicate key value is (4badb078-13be-e311-b2b9-080027842291, name, 1033, Jun 19 2015  8:13AM, 0). The statement has been terminated."
```

We tracked down the flawed component through GUID (i.e. 4badb078-13be-e311-b2b9-080027842291 in this case). We managed to detect and remove certain charts but after doing this repetitive action, it took us to the Chart which was dependent on Account and a custom Entity, Describing-In short, that this may lead to problem sometime later (i.e. after we try to removing dependency).

Please let us know if anyone has seen this issue before. Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I had a problem with updating from 2011 to 2013, sadly I couldn't find a solution besides opening the Customization Xml and remove the Tag that was creating the problem. In my case what created the problem was a Quick creation form that wasn't even present in the solution explorer. This is totally unsupported tho.

Comment: We had similar issue migrating crm 2011 to 2013 and the problem was in translations. We also had to remove this from customization.xml for it to work

Answer (score 0):

try removing the entity that causes the problem from the solution.
import the solution and afterwards import the original solution.
sometimes CRM has problems with dependencies.